# Problem calculating tangent space

Tags: mesh, normal-mapping

I am currently writing a 3D rendering engine for educational purposes. In general everything is working except that I am chasing down a problem in my cube mesh / tangent calculations that I can't find.
This picture shows the tangent fragment position I receive in the fragment shader. As you can see, there's clearly an issue here:

[image: Tangent fragment position]

I tried to find this issue for quite some time - at this point I'm probably missing the obvious. What I have been trying to do so far:

- Ensuring that it's not a winding order issue: In that case face culling would make the faces disappear - that's not happening here.
- Tripple checking tangent calculation (function `mesh::calculate_tangents()`)
- Tripple checking TBN matrix calculation

Unfortunately, I am unable to find the problem. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

To get started, here's my `vertex` struct definition:

```
    struct vertex {
        glm::vec3 position;
        glm::vec3 normal;
        glm::vec2 texture_uv;
        glm::vec3 tangent;
        glm::vec3 bitangent;
    };
```

`cube.cpp`:

```cpp
cube::cube()
{
    constexpr std::size_t vertices_count = 36;

    std::array<glm::vec3, vertices_count> positions = {
            glm::vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),
            glm::vec3( 0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f),
            glm::vec3( 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),
            glm::vec3( 0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f),
            glm::vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),
            glm::vec3(-0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f),

            glm::vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f),
            glm::vec3( 0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f),
            glm::vec3( 0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f),
            glm::vec3( 0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f),
            glm::vec3(-0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f),
            glm::vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f),

            glm::vec3(-0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f),
            glm::vec3(-0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f),
            glm::vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),
            glm::vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),
            glm::vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f),
            glm::vec3(-0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f),

            glm::vec3( 0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f),
            glm::vec3( 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),
            glm::vec3( 0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f),
            glm::vec3( 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),
            glm::vec3( 0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f),
            glm::vec3( 0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f),

            glm::vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),
            glm::vec3( 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),
            glm::vec3( 0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f),
            glm::vec3( 0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f),
            glm::vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f),
            glm::vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),

            glm::vec3(-0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f),
            glm::vec3( 0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f),
            glm::vec3( 0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f),
            glm::vec3( 0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f),
            glm::vec3(-0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f),
            glm::vec3(-0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f),
    };

    std::array<glm::vec2, vertices_count> texture_uv = {
            glm::vec2(0.0f, 0.0f),
            glm::vec2(1.0f, 1.0f),
            glm::vec2(1.0f, 0.0f),
            glm::vec2(1.0f, 1.0f),
            glm::vec2(0.0f, 0.0f),
            glm::vec2(0.0f, 1.0f),

            glm::vec2(0.0f, 0.0f),
            glm::vec2(1.0f, 0.0f),
            glm::vec2(1.0f, 1.0f),
            glm::vec2(1.0f, 1.0f),
            glm::vec2(0.0f, 1.0f),
            glm::vec2(0.0f, 0.0f),

            glm::vec2(1.0f, 0.0f),
            glm::vec2(1.0f, 1.0f),
            glm::vec2(0.0f, 1.0f),
            glm::vec2(0.0f, 1.0f),
            glm::vec2(0.0f, 0.0f),
            glm::vec2(1.0f, 0.0f),

            glm::vec2(1.0f, 0.0f),
            glm::vec2(0.0f, 1.0f),
            glm::vec2(1.0f, 1.0f),
            glm::vec2(0.0f, 1.0f),
            glm::vec2(1.0f, 0.0f),
            glm::vec2(0.0f, 0.0f),

            glm::vec2(0.0f, 1.0f),
            glm::vec2(1.0f, 1.0f),
            glm::vec2(1.0f, 0.0f),
            glm::vec2(1.0f, 0.0f),
            glm::vec2(0.0f, 0.0f),
            glm::vec2(0.0f, 1.0f),

            glm::vec2(0.0f, 1.0f),
            glm::vec2(1.0f, 0.0f),
            glm::vec2(1.0f, 1.0f),
            glm::vec2(1.0f, 0.0f),
            glm::vec2(0.0f, 1.0f),
            glm::vec2(0.0f, 0.0f),
    };

    std::array<glm::vec3, vertices_count> normals = {
            glm::vec3( 0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f),
            glm::vec3( 0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f),
            glm::vec3( 0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f),
            glm::vec3( 0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f),
            glm::vec3( 0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f),
            glm::vec3( 0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f),

            glm::vec3( 0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f),
            glm::vec3( 0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f),
            glm::vec3( 0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f),
            glm::vec3( 0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f),
            glm::vec3( 0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f),
            glm::vec3( 0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f),

            glm::vec3(-1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f),
            glm::vec3(-1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f),
            glm::vec3(-1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f),
            glm::vec3(-1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f),
            glm::vec3(-1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f),
            glm::vec3(-1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f),

            glm::vec3( 1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f),
            glm::vec3( 1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f),
            glm::vec3( 1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f),
            glm::vec3( 1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f),
            glm::vec3( 1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f),
            glm::vec3( 1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f),

            glm::vec3( 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f),
            glm::vec3( 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f),
            glm::vec3( 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f),
            glm::vec3( 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f),
            glm::vec3( 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f),
            glm::vec3( 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f),

            glm::vec3( 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f),
            glm::vec3( 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f),
            glm::vec3( 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f),
            glm::vec3( 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f),
            glm::vec3( 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f),
            glm::vec3( 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f),
    };

    // Build indices
    std::vector<GLuint> indices;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < vertices_count; ++i) {
        indices.emplace_back(static_cast<GLuint>(i));
    }

    // Build vertices
    std::vector<vertex> vertices = build_vertices(std::move(positions), std::move(normals), std::move(texture_uv));

    // Textures
    std::vector<texture> textures;
    // ...

    // Create mesh
    mesh m(std::move(vertices), std::move(indices), std::move(textures));
    m.calculate_tangents();
    set_mesh(std::move(m));
}
```

Function `mesh::calculate_tangents()`:

```
void mesh::calculate_tangents()
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < m_indices.size()-2; ++i)
    {
        // Honor indices order
        const GLuint& index1 = m_indices.at(i + 0);
        const GLuint& index2 = m_indices.at(i + 1);
        const GLuint& index3 = m_indices.at(i + 2);

        // Get the three adjacent vertices
        const auto& v1 = m_vertices[index1];
        const auto& v2 = m_vertices[index2];
        const auto& v3 = m_vertices[index3];

        // Edges & delta-UVs
        const glm::vec3& edge1 = v2.position - v1.position;
        const glm::vec3& edge2 = v3.position - v1.position;
        const glm::vec2& deltaUV1 = v2.texture_uv - v1.texture_uv;
        const glm::vec2& deltaUV2 = v3.texture_uv - v1.texture_uv;

        const GLfloat f = 1.0f / (deltaUV1.x * deltaUV2.y - deltaUV2.x * deltaUV1.y);

        // Calculate tangent
        glm::vec3 tangent;
        tangent.x = f * (deltaUV2.y * edge1.x - deltaUV1.y * edge2.x);
        tangent.y = f * (deltaUV2.y * edge1.y - deltaUV1.y * edge2.y);
        tangent.z = f * (deltaUV2.y * edge1.z - deltaUV1.y * edge2.z);
        tangent = glm::normalize(tangent);
        m_vertices[index1].tangent = tangent;
        m_vertices[index2].tangent = tangent;
        m_vertices[index3].tangent = tangent;

        // Calculate bitangent
        glm::vec3 bitangent;
        bitangent.x = f * (-deltaUV2.x * edge1.x + deltaUV1.x * edge2.x);
        bitangent.y = f * (-deltaUV2.x * edge1.y + deltaUV1.x * edge2.y);
        bitangent.z = f * (-deltaUV2.x * edge1.z + deltaUV1.x * edge2.z);
        bitangent = glm::normalize(bitangent);
        m_vertices[index1].bitangent = bitangent;
        m_vertices[index2].bitangent = bitangent;
        m_vertices[index3].bitangent = bitangent;
    }
}
```

This is how I calculate the TBN matrix in the vertex shader:

```
    mat3 normalMatrix = transpose(inverse(mat3(model)));
    vec3 T = normalize(normalMatrix * a_tangent);
    vec3 N = normalize(normalMatrix * a_normal);
    T = normalize(T - dot(T, N) * N);
    vec3 B = cross(N, T);

    mat3 TBN = transpose(mat3(T, B, N));
    vs_out.TangentLightPos = TBN * light.position;
    vs_out.TangentViewPos  = TBN * camera_position;
    vs_out.TangentFragPos  = TBN * vs_out.fragment_position;
```

For completeness, here's my `mesh` class definition:

```
    class mesh
    {
    public:
        // Construction
        mesh();
        mesh(std::vector<vertex>&& vertices, std::vector<GLuint>&& indices, std::vector<texture>&& textures);
        mesh(const mesh& other) = delete;
        mesh(mesh&& other);
        virtual ~mesh() = default;

        // Operators
        mesh& operator=(mesh&& rhs);

        // Common
        void calculate_tangents();
        void render(rendering::shader& shader) const;

    private:
        std::vector<vertex> m_vertices;
        std::vector<GLuint> m_indices;
        std::vector<texture> m_textures;

        GLuint m_vbo;   // Vertex buffer object
        GLuint m_vao;   // Vertex array object
        GLuint m_ebo;   // Element buffer object

        void finalize();
    };
```